# How can we build a probability censoring function such that the survival function of Kaplan Meier will not be effected?

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

If i have the complete data of a subject (un-censored), How can I design a probability function for censoring the data such that the survival function value will not change?

What is the condition for censoring the data of such a function in each point in time?

Thanks in advance!!

Edit:
KM survival function is defined as:
$S(\tau_k) = \Pi^k_{i=0}(1-d_i\div n_i)$
Where $d_i$ is the number of people with event at every time interval.
and $n_i$ is the people at risk at every time interval.

So cosidering this, what is the condition of censoring data so that at each time interval, the KM survival function value of the complete data will have the same value as the KM survival function value of the censored-version of the same data?

Comment: A Kaplan-Meier curve has a drop at each event time. So if you censor a case with an event you will necessarily change the Kaplan-Meier curve. There will no longer be a drop at that event time. Please edit the question to say more about what you are trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: But if we censor a person that had an event at time $\tau_k$, then there will be less people, as well as 1 less person that has an event, meaning the the drop would be equal to when we did not censored the event of that same person.

Comment: Agree with @EdM that censoring data changes the survival curve. As a very simple example, imagine a dataset with 1 individual who has an event at t=1 - the survival function drops from 1 to 0 at t=1. If you censor them before t=1, the survival function remains at 1 the whole time. As another example, take a large population where everyone has an event - the survival function drops to 0. If the individual with the last event is censored instead, the survival function does not drop to 0.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Look at the answer that clementzach wrote, Im trying to understand the condition for such phenomenon to happen

Comment: I now see how under some specific circumstances you can generate a censored curve that matches the uncensored curve. It can't be done in general, however; it requires multiple individuals who share event times and a particular censoring regime that won't always work even then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do what you seek if, as in the answer from @clementzach, you have multiple events at each event time and you can choose the censored cases very specifically. You have written the Kaplan-Meier estimator as:

$$\hat S(\tau_k) = \prod_{i=0}^k\left[ 1- \frac{d_i}{n_i}\right] $$

where $d_i$ is the number of cases having the event at time $\tau_i$ and $n_i$ is the corresponding number at risk at that time. At each event time $\tau_i$, the ratio $d_i/n_i$ represents the fractional change of the survival curve from  its previous value toward 0 survival. So as you censor you must do so in a way that $d_i/n_i$ is unchanged for all event times $\tau_i$.

If you have any event time $\tau_j$ with only one individual having the event at that time (as I implicitly assumed in my comments) and right-censor that individual's event time, $d_j=0 $ after censoring. Thus $\hat S(\tau_j)$ no longer has a drop at time $\tau_j$, changing the Kaplan-Meier curve. The number at risk will be the same after $\tau_j$, but the baseline from which the next event leads to a drop will be higher than previously. Thus the magnitude of a drop at a subsequent event time might also change.

Similarly, consider a one-individual event time at $\tau_j$ with some later event times right-censored before $\tau_j$. Then the Kaplan-Meier curve after censoring is also changed from the uncensored version. In this case, although $d_j$ is still 1, $n_j$ is now lower than without censoring so the drop in the curve at $\tau_j$ is greater.

Thus a necessary condition to have a completely unchanged Kaplan-Meier curve is to only censor event times of individuals who share event times with others and not to censor event times subsequent to times at which only 1 individual has an event.

You also have to be very careful in how you choose the individuals whose event times you censor. You have to do that in a way that keeps the ratio of event numbers to those at-risk, $d_i /n_i$, unchanged at each event time $i$. As the answer from @clementzach (+1) shows, you might be able to do this if you censor between event times *proportionately* from those still at risk at each subsequent event time. (Random censoring leads to random changes in $d_i/n_i$ from the uncensored situation.) That is, you have to make sure that the changes in numbers of cases with events is exactly balanced by the change in the number at risk at each event time.

One way to do that is, between 2 event times, to evaluate the number still at risk at each subsequent event time and censor the *exact same proportion* from those having events at each subsequent event time. For a completely unchanged Kaplan-Meier curve you also, however, need a large enough sample size that you don't end up with rounding differences in $d_i/n_i$ between the censored and uncensored situations.

Here's an example with a large number of cases and only 4 event times. Set up an uncensored data set with 400 cases, 100 having each event time, in order of their event times.

```
df400 <- data.frame(time=rep(1:4,times=rep(100,4)),event=1)
```

Make a copy to censor

```
df400cens <-df400
```

Before the first event time, censor the same fraction of those at risk from those having events at each event time. Here, censor 20% from each event time prior to the first event time.

```
df400cens[c(1:20,101:120,201:220,301:320),"event"] <- 0
df400cens[c(1:20,101:120,201:220,301:320),"time"] <- 0.5
```

Between the first and the second event times, censor some fraction of those still at risk, again with the same fraction censored from those still at risk at subsequent times. Here, censoring 10 out of 80 still at risk for each subsequent event time.

```
df400cens[c(121:130,221:230,321:330),"event"] <- 0
df400cens[c(121:130,221:230,321:330),"time"] <- 1.5
```

Similarly censor between the second and third event times, here censoring 30 of 70 still at risk at each subsequent event time.

```
df400cens[c(231:260,331:360),"event"] <- 0
df400cens[c(231:260,331:360),"time"] <- 2.5
```

Censor as many as you'd like of those still at risk before the last event time, so long as you leave at least 1.

```
df400cens[361:399,"event"] <- 0
df400cens[361:399,"time"] <- 3.5
```

Compare the uncensored and censored survival curves. The dashed blue censored curve exactly matches the original survival function in black.

```
plot(survfit(Surv(time,event)~1,data=df400),conf.int=FALSE,mark.time=TRUE,bty="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Fraction surviving")
lines(survfit(Surv(time,event)~1,data=df400cens),conf.int=FALSE,mark.time=TRUE,bty="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Fraction surviving",lty=2,col="blue",lwd=3)
```

[image: uncensored and censored KM curves that coincide]

So although it is sometimes possible to have a censored Kaplan-Meier curve that matches the original uncensored version in terms of the survival function, it requires a very specific set of circumstances, careful attention to proportionality of censoring of those still at risk, and a large enough data set that you don't end up with differences from rounding.

Answer (score 2):

The Kaplan-Meier curve will approximate the survival function from complete data when the censoring times are independent of failure times.

To implement this, generate n censoring times from an exponential distribution, one for each participant, with a similar median survival time as seen in the complete data.

For each participant, if their censoring time is less than their survival time, censor that participant's time at the censoring time generated and mark them as censored. If their generated censoring time is greater than their actual survival time, leave that participant's survival time complete (they will be recorded as having experienced an event at the actual failure time).

This [resource](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Elutian/coursepdf/STAT331unit3.pdf) contains more details.

The best way to get intuition on Kaplan-Meier estimators is to do a lot of them by hand, and get an understanding of how it works.

Maybe a reasonable comparable example would be if I wanted to see what proportion of the lights in a panel of 300 light bulbs were still good. If all the bulbs were wired correctly (no censoring), I could turn the panel on, and count how many turned on (let's say that 1/3 of the bulbs are good, so 100 would turn on).

Now, let's say that I knew that 1/4 of the bulbs were wired incorrectly (censored) so I could never observe the bulbs turning on regardless of whether the lights were good. In this situation, turning on the panel would show that 75 bulbs turned on. If I didn't account for censoring, and said that 300 bulbs were in the "risk set", I would conclude that 75/300 (1/4) of the bulbs were good.

But, if I decided to use 225 bulbs that I knew were wired correctly as my "risk set", I would conclude that 75/225 (1/3) of the bulbs were wired correctly. This would give me the correct estimate.

Here is a worked example:

Let's say you have a population of 1,000 individuals, with 500 surviving to 1 month, 200 surviving to 2 months, and 100 surviving to 3 months.

| Time | $n_i$ | $d_i$ | # in risk set | Number Censored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 | 0 |
| 1 | 500 | 500 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2 | 200 | 300 | 500 | 0 |
| 3 | 100 | 100 | 200 | 0 |

If there was no censoring, the Kaplan-Meier estimate at 1 month would be 500/1000 = 0.5. The estimate at 2 months would be (500/1000) * (200/500) = 200/1000 = 0.2. At 3 months, the estimate would be (500/1000) * (200/500) * (100/200) = 100 / 1000 0.1. Notice how the numerators and denominators cancel out in the case of complete data.

Now, let's say that 1/2 of the participants drop out of the study at 15 days (independent of survival time). So, you have 500 people recorded as censored at 0 months. Then, on average, 250 people would be recorded as making it to 1 month, 100 people would be recorded as making it to 2 months, and 50 people would be recorded as making it to 3 months.

| Time | $n_i$ | $d_i$ | # in risk set | Number Censored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 | 500 |
| 1 | 500 | 250 | 500 | 0 |
| 2 | 200 | 150 | 250 | 0 |
| 3 | 100 | 50 | 150 | 0 |

The Kaplan-Meier estimate under this censoring at 1 month would be 250/500 = 0.5. The estimate at 2 months would be (250/500) * (100/250) = 100/500 0.2, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may I ask you to please provide some intuition by an example or an explanation as to how the method you proposed will give the same survival function value to both the censored data and the complete data? Also, what do you mean by failure times?

Comment: Sorry, I use failure times as a synonym for survival times.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, yet ill still be glad if you could explain the intuition.. the paper is quite long, and my "mathematical english" is not that good

Comment: Sometimes, my ability to determine what is and what isn't "mathematical English" isn't that good either. Let me know if that edit helps

Comment: This certainly shows the usefulness of the Kaplan-Meier estimator of the true survival function. But I don’t think it answers the question as posed. If you already have a complete Kaplan-Meier curve based completely on uncensored data, I don’t see how you can get the survival function completely unchanged if you start censoring. Yes, you will still get a close approximation to the true survival function if censoring is uninformative, but it won’t be unchanged from the uncensored original.

Comment: In the example above @clementzach did show that the survival function value can be the same at the time itervals depends on how we censor, But it still not quite what i asked.  i am having a difficulty understanding what is the condition for this to happen (basically generalizing from the example that clementzach provided)

Comment: i have been trying to set properly the condition for both survival function to be the same at the different intervals in time, what i got is that if a person is being censored in the time iterval just before his event, we will get the same survival function value. Do you guys believe it sounds correct?

Comment: The condition is that censoring be "uninformative". I've always assumed that this meant that the censoring density should be essentially the same as the event density. Another way of stating it would be that a censoring event should not affect the future probabilities. So if you had a set that was partitioned into "to-be-censored" and "to-be-followed-to-event" with the same distribution that it would seem to me possible that these times could alternate rather than the censored times always being before the event times.

Comment: I think the second example where a substantial proportion were all censored at 15 days would not qualify as "uninformative". It would create a sudden decrease in the risk set and thus would make the probability of failure substantially higher for subsequent times.

Comment: @StrugglingResearcher no, that's not correct if you want to have _exactly_ "the same survival function." If you censor someone who does not share an event time with others, then the KM curve is necessarily changed thereafter. If you censor someone with a late event time at a time prior to a time where only one individual has an event, the KM curve is also necessarily changed. What you seek to do is only possible in very specific circumstances, illustrated in my revised answer.